# To convert Date column(in integer (YYYYMMDD ) of a dataset to Date in python

Tags: python-3.x, date

I'm working on a Data set which contains "Date" column which is of int64 as a datatype. It is in YYYYMMDD format. I want it should be in YYYY/MM/DD format. Please help me to convert it to Date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dates = pd.DataFrame({"dates_int": [20190103, 20190206, 20190502]})
dates['dates_dt'] = dates['dates_int'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(str(x), '%Y%m%d').strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
```

Comment: This code solved my problem..Amazing..Thanks a ton!!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to vote up and mark the answer as answered.